# Get process from control handle

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, winapi

I have a handle to a control that belongs to another process in the system.
How can I get the process it belongs to? I've tried looking up a suitable function but haven't found much.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you going to do once you figure out what process it belongs to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose that by "handle to a control", you mean a HWND.

Then, use [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx)

```
HWND hWndToSomeControl;

[...]

DWORD dwPid;
GetWindowThreadProcessId( hWndToSomeControl, &dwPid );
```

Edit: error control (Tested on Windows 7):

```
HWND hWndToSomeControl;

[...]

DWORD dwPid;
DWORD dwTid = GetWindowThreadProcessId( hWndToSomeControl, &dwPid );
if ( dwTid == 0 ) {
    DWORD dwLE = GetLastError(); // may be 1400 ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE
    [...]
}
```